# Opening separate url in iframe ipad/phonegap

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

I want to open the url in same page where I added iframe tag. But it opens url in separate window.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your problem, could you be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

you could always have a lightbox such as prettyPhoto load the iframe right ontop of your current site?  Or you can try to add target="_self" to the  tag.  Generally that state is assumed if you don't specify otherwise.  To see how a pretty photo loads an iFrame you can go here:

[http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#!prettyPhoto[iframes]/0/](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#!prettyPhoto%5Biframes%5D/0/)

Hope this helps.